# Uploading files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, file-upload

I want to make a section in my site where visitors can upload files (pdfs). How can this be done?

Also, after the pdf is uploaded, I need a link to that file. Rather than using a boring text link, I was thinking of having a thumbnail graphic of the first page of the pdf. Is there a tool out there that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the *Uploading part* you might consider [ActsAsAttachment](http://techno-weenie.net/articles/acts_as_attachment) or (as already stated) [Paperclip](http://www.thoughtbot.com/projects/paperclip).

I am not aware of any plugin for rails which is able to *create/read thumbnails from PDF files* automatically, but you could invoke [LibExtractpr](http://gnunet.org/libextractor/) or [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) from your code.

Additionally you might take a look at the [rGhost Gem](http://github.com/shairontoledo/rghost/tree/master) which (as the documentation states) is a "a document creation and conversion API" which essentially should be a GhostScript Wrapper for Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst, not directly addressing the PDF thumbnail issue "The Rails Way" is doing a series on uploading/downloading files with Rails which would be useful with large files like your PDFs.

**[Uploading Files](http://www.therailsway.com/2009/4/23/uploading-files)**: basically, they have an Apache module called ModPorter which speeds up the parsing of the multipart HTTP request containing the upload.

**[Downloading Files](http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right)**: use X-SendFile to let Apache serve the download, once your Rails app has performed any user authentication required