# Are there any Ruby gems for easy to do image uploading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, rubygems

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Uploading files in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116353/uploading-files-in-ruby-on-rails)
>   [Uploading files in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741714/uploading-files-in-rails)
>   [Uploading Pictures Ruby on Rails…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857187/uploading-pictures-ruby-on-rails)

I am doing a web site which allow users to upload images, is there any way to simplify the upload process?

Comment: I'd mark is as dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741714/uploading-files-in-rails (among other similar questions, this one has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a few rails plugin, attachement_fu and paperclip i think are amongst the best

Here is a tutorial on railscast for paperclip http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip and here is an attachement fu tutorial http://clarkware.com/cgi/blosxom/2007/02/24#FileUploadFu

Answer (score 1):

Using the Stackoverflow searchbox with [file upload ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=file+upload+ruby-on-rails) these three (at least) look promising:

[uploading a file to a website with ruby/rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390993/uploading-a-file-to-a-website-with-ruby-rails)

[Uploading files in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116353/uploading-files-in-ruby-on-rails)

[Uploading files in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741714/uploading-files-in-rails)